# Django profile model : Strange Error : Extending Auth User Model

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, relational-database

**Unexplained results due to OneToOne field ( I suppose )**

See the bottom for my problems

**Output in terminal :**

```
In [21]: profile = User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com')
In [22]: profile
Out[22]: <User: jlennon@beatles.com>

In [23]: profile = User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile

In [24]: profile
Out[24]: <Users: ExampleUser1>
In [25]: profile = User.objects.get(id=2).profile

In [26]: profile
Out[26]: <Users: ExampleUser1>

In [27]: User.objects.get(id=2)
Out[27]: <User: jlennon@beatles.com>

In [28]: User.objects.get(id=4)
Out[28]: <User: ExampleUser1>
```

**models.py :**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    user_Id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    user_fname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    user_lname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    user_email = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    joining_date = models.DateTimeField()
    user_dob = models.DateField()
    user_country = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
    user_gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    user_pic = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user_about = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Users'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_users'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myWebsite.Users'
```

**my database :**

```
mysql> select id, username, email from auth_user where id=1 or id=2 or id=4;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | username            | email               |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | admin               | admin@admin.com     |
|  2 | jlennon@beatles.com | jlennon@beatles.com |
|  4 | ExampleUser1        | user1@example.com   |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**My Users table (tbl_users):**

```
+---------+--------------+---------------------------+
| user_id | user_name    | user_email                |
+---------+--------------+---------------------------+
|       2 | ExampleUser1 | user1@example.com         |
|       3 | Crazy        | crazy@crazy.com           |
+---------+--------------+---------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think since I don't have a user in `tbl_users` , due to which I may be getting erroneous output. Am I right ??

How is the ***OneToOneField*** **,** linking `User` table from `django.contrib.auth.mmodels` to `Users` in my apps `models.py` ?

I think the answer to the above question may make it clear for me as to how should I proceed with making profile model.

The `tbl_users` table is from a old **PHP** project which I didn't want to abandon and that is why it still has `user_password` field in it's model ( cause it has been imported using ***inspectdb***.

However I would be moving to creating profiles while registering as I have read somewhere on making that , I think then I won't have to worry about this issue cause then I would have profile object for each of the profiles.

But still I wanted to know **how to correct in the ongoing scenario** and **what am I doing wrong** ?

---

#EDIT : #

New **Users** class as suggested to change

```
class Users(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    user_Id = models.IntegerField()
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    user_fname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    user_lname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    user_email = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=60)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    joining_date = models.DateTimeField()
    user_dob = models.DateField()
    user_country = CountryField()
    user_gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    user_pic = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user_about = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Users'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_users'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

**MySQL table Description**:

```
mysql> desc tbl_users;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+------------------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default                      | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+------------------------------+-------+
| user_id       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_name     | varchar(25)  | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_fname    | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_lname    | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_email    | varchar(60)  | NO   | PRI | NULL                         |       |
| user_password | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| joining_date  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_dob      | date         | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_country  | varchar(3)   | YES  |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_gender   | char(1)      | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_pic      | char(255)    | YES  |     | ../images/provideAnImage.jpg |       |
| user_about    | varchar(512) | YES  |     | NULL                         |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+------------------------------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But still the output which I am getting is :

```
In [4]: User.objects.get(email='user1@example.com').profile
Out[4]: <Users: ExampleUser3>
In [5]: User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com')
Out[5]: <User: jlennon@beatles.com>

In [6]: User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile
Out[6]: <Users: ExampleUser1>
```

##And the when I tried to see the query going in the back : ##

```
In [7]: User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile.query
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-201041bc7f1c> in <module>()
----> 1 User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile.query

AttributeError: 'Users' object has no attribute 'query'

In [8]: User.objects.filter(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile.query
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c4827b8b2ee1> in <module>()
----> 1 User.objects.filter(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile.query

AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'profile'

In [9]: User.objects.filter(email='jlennon@beatles.com').query
Out[9]: <django.db.models.sql.query.Query at 0x7fefe8741f90>
```

### So I found an alternative

**However do tell me a better way ...**

```
In [10]: for conn in connection.queries:
    ...:     print str(conn)+"\n\n"
    ...:     
{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u'SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL'}


{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u'SELECT VERSION()'}


{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u"SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`password`, `auth_user`.`last_login`, `auth_user`.`is_superuser`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`, `auth_user`.`last_name`, `auth_user`.`email`, `auth_user`.`is_staff`, `auth_user`.`is_active`, `auth_user`.`date_joined` FROM `auth_user` WHERE `auth_user`.`email` = 'user2@example.com'"}


{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u'SELECT `tbl_users`.`user_id`, `tbl_users`.`user_Id`, `tbl_users`.`user_name`, `tbl_users`.`user_fname`, `tbl_users`.`user_lname`, `tbl_users`.`user_email`, `tbl_users`.`user_password`, `tbl_users`.`joining_date`, `tbl_users`.`user_dob`, `tbl_users`.`user_country`, `tbl_users`.`user_gender`, `tbl_users`.`user_pic`, `tbl_users`.`user_about` FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `tbl_users`.`user_id` = 4'}


{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u"SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`password`, `auth_user`.`last_login`, `auth_user`.`is_superuser`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`, `auth_user`.`last_name`, `auth_user`.`email`, `auth_user`.`is_staff`, `auth_user`.`is_active`, `auth_user`.`date_joined` FROM `auth_user` WHERE `auth_user`.`email` = 'jlennon@beatles.com'"}


{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u"SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`password`, `auth_user`.`last_login`, `auth_user`.`is_superuser`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`, `auth_user`.`last_name`, `auth_user`.`email`, `auth_user`.`is_staff`, `auth_user`.`is_active`, `auth_user`.`date_joined` FROM `auth_user` WHERE `auth_user`.`email` = 'jlennon@beatles.com'"}


{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u'SELECT `tbl_users`.`user_id`, `tbl_users`.`user_Id`, `tbl_users`.`user_name`, `tbl_users`.`user_fname`, `tbl_users`.`user_lname`, `tbl_users`.`user_email`, `tbl_users`.`user_password`, `tbl_users`.`joining_date`, `tbl_users`.`user_dob`, `tbl_users`.`user_country`, `tbl_users`.`user_gender`, `tbl_users`.`user_pic`, `tbl_users`.`user_about` FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `tbl_users`.`user_id` = 2'}


{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u"SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`password`, `auth_user`.`last_login`, `auth_user`.`is_superuser`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`, `auth_user`.`last_name`, `auth_user`.`email`, `auth_user`.`is_staff`, `auth_user`.`is_active`, `auth_user`.`date_joined` FROM `auth_user` WHERE `auth_user`.`email` = 'jlennon@beatles.com'"}


{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u'SELECT `tbl_users`.`user_id`, `tbl_users`.`user_Id`, `tbl_users`.`user_name`, `tbl_users`.`user_fname`, `tbl_users`.`user_lname`, `tbl_users`.`user_email`, `tbl_users`.`user_password`, `tbl_users`.`joining_date`, `tbl_users`.`user_dob`, `tbl_users`.`user_country`, `tbl_users`.`user_gender`, `tbl_users`.`user_pic`, `tbl_users`.`user_about` FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `tbl_users`.`user_id` = 2'}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure exactly whats going on, but a problem I had a while back with creating users was that I was creating them by calling 'newUser = User.objects.create()', when searching for the users using queries I could not find any. When I instead used 'newUser = User.objects.create_user()', I could then query them correctly

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for **[AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)**

You have specified `AUTH_PROFILE_MODEL` but as long as you don't specify `AUTH_USER_MODEL` Django will be using its built in user model only.

### EDIT:

Unfortunately I cant go deep to prove but it seems that django is constructing Foreign Key relationship query on a primary key basis. So actually the query for

```
User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile
```

becomes something similar to:

```
SELECT tu.id FROM auth_user as au JOIN tbl_users as tu ON au.id=tu.id WHERE au.email='jlennon@beatles.com';
```

But since `id=2` for `jlennon@beatles.com` when it matches with your `tbl_users` it fetches the object which corresponding to id `2` which is `Aniket`. Which is the reason for this weird behaviour. I believe setting **[email as PK](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#primary-key)** in the Users model should solve the issue for you.

### How to prove?

You can try running what did in the console and add `.query` to it to find the exact sql query Django runs. In this case for ex: `User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile.query` it must be something similar to the query above.

Hope this helps. Also take into consideration that [AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15937) is depreciated. Given your scenario I leave that to you.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to avoid and due to which I preferred **OneToOneField** in the `Users` model

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but it still isn't working , yes actually it is getting id from auth and fetching the corresponding data from tbl_users I tried changing the **PK** to email field and did change it but still it fetches the same values......I have applied the migrations but still no effect **AND** one more thing you can use query only on _Queryset_ objects and not on **Users** object which the _profile_ changes it to `User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile.query
AttributeError    Traceback (most rece...)
User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile.query
`

Comment: [@thulasi-ram](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6323666/thulasi-ram)Check my edited question